# Getting this 'General Server Vulnerabilities' and 'HTTP TRACE method is enabled' security concern in Ionic application in VA-PT

Tags: android, ios, angular, security, ionic-framework

Our team has encountered critical security concerns within our Ionic application. These issues are rooted in the use of specific APIs by our Cordova plugins.

**1. General Server Vulnerabilities:**

In both our Android and iOS applications, the following APIs invoked by our Cordova plugins have raised significant alarm due to "General Server Vulnerabilities":

**For Android:**

- `play.googleapis.com:443/c2dm/register3`
- `https://play.googleapis.com:443/c2dm/register3`

**For iOS:**

- `apple-finance.query.yahoo.com:443/v1/yql/applewf/multiquote`
- `iid.googleapis.com:443/iid/register`
- `https://iid.googleapis.com:443/iid/register`

Despite extensive efforts, we have been unsuccessful in finding a viable solution to mitigate these concerns.

**2. HTTP TRACE Method is Enabled:**

Additionally, our Cordova plugins have utilized the following APIs, leading to the discovery that the HTTP TRACE method is enabled, posing a substantial risk:

**For Android:**

- `https://clientservices.googleapis.com:443/chrome-variations/se osname=android_webview&milestone=88`

**For iOS:**

- `https://api-glb-aaps1b.smoot.apple.com:443/search`
- `https://app-measurement.com:443`
- `https://api.smoot.apple.com:443`

We are uncertain about the appropriate steps to disable the HTTP TRACE method and effectively mitigate this vulnerability.

**Plugins in Use:**

Our Ionic application incorporates the following Cordova plugins:

```
"@awesome-cordova-plugins/android-permissions": "^5.45.0",
"@awesome-cordova-plugins/app-version": "^5.45.0",
"@awesome-cordova-plugins/camera": "^5.45.0",
"@awesome-cordova-plugins/chooser": "^5.45.0",
"@awesome-cordova-plugins/clipboard": "^5.45.0",
"@awesome-cordova-plugins/core": "^5.45.0",
"@awesome-cordova-plugins/dialogs": "^5.45.0",
"@awesome-cordova-plugins/fcm": "^6.4.0",
"@awesome-cordova-plugins/file": "^5.45.0",
"@awesome-cordova-plugins/file-opener": "^5.45.0",
"@awesome-cordova-plugins/file-path": "^5.45.0",
"@awesome-cordova-plugins/file-transfer": "^5.45.0",
"@awesome-cordova-plugins/image-picker": "^6.4.0",
"@awesome-cordova-plugins/keyboard": "^5.45.0",
"@awesome-cordova-plugins/local-notifications": "^5.45.0",
"@awesome-cordova-plugins/network": "^5.44.0",
"@awesome-cordova-plugins/streaming-media": "^5.45.0",
"@awesome-cordova-plugins/toast": "^5.45.0",
"@ionic-native/browser-tab": "^5.36.0",
"@ionic-native/core": "^5.36.0",
"@ionic-native/crop": "^5.36.0",
"@ionic-native/file": "^5.36.0",
"@ionic-native/file-picker": "^5.36.0",
"@ionic-native/http": "^5.36.0",
"@ionic-native/image-picker": "^5.36.0",
"@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^5.36.0",
"@ionic-native/keyboard": "^5.36.0",
"@ionic/angular": "^6.2.4",
"@ionic/angular-server": "^6.2.5",
"@ionic/cordova-builders": "^7.0.0",
"@ionic/storage": "^2.1.3",
"@ngrx/effects": "^14.3.0",
"@ngrx/store": "^14.3.0",
"ajv-keywords": "^5.1.0",
"autolinker": "^4.0.0",
"chart.js": "^4.3.0",
"cordova-browser": "6.0.0",
"cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": "^1.1.3",
"cordova-plugin-iroot": "^3.1.0",
"cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker": "^2.3.2",
"crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
"dialog": "^0.3.1",
"domsanitizer": "^0.2.3",
"eslint-plugin-ngrx": "^2.1.4",
"ionic-5-gallery-modal": "^0.2.25",
"ionic-native": "^2.9.0",
"ionic-selectable": "^4.9.0",
"ionic4-star-rating": "^1.1.1",
"ios-sim": "^9.0.0",
"moment": "^2.29.4",
"ng-circle-progress": "^1.6.0",
"ng2-charts": "^4.1.1",
"ngx-linky": "^4.0.0",
"rxjs": "~6.6.0",
```

How to address these critical security vulnerabilities?

Comment: There is nothing your app can do about the TRACE method being enabled. It is enabled on the server side and needs to be disabled there. You can try logging security vulnerability incidents with the owners of those servers, but the TRACE method may not even pose a problem and "General Server Vulnerabilities" also sounds like nothing in your control, but it is also a fairly useless description of the issues.